# PARENT_ACTIVITY parent background

Tags: android

I have a problem when going backward.

my message comes from "NotificationManager" and when I click on the notification, it goes directly to the activity2 chat, bypassing the activity1, when activity1 is in the background

My structure

Activity1 - > Activity2 chat

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.Chat"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.Chat" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.Chat" />
        </activity>
```

Images :

Pass 1 : My activity1 is background, and I'm in destock

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPKSN.png

Pass 2 Click notification and go activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQhVl.png

pass 3 I click to go back :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCyqP.png

go to desktock

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPKSN.png

Comment: How can it be that your Activity is parent of itself? Are you your own father? You'd probably need to rethink that, or clarify the context.

Comment: I tried : android:parentActivityName="com.example.parentChat" and into metadata  android:value="com.example.ParentChat" but not work

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want your notification to open `Activity2` (which currently works), and then when you go, Up from there, open `Activity1`. You already set up the parent activity in the manifest, so that's fine, but what you also need to do is **create a back stack** in the `PendingIntent` of your notification.

```
...
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#DirectEntry

You probably also need to distinguish parent and child activity, I don't think it's a good design to have the same activity opening itself.